# dojo.hitch scope issue in onsubmit dojo/method

Tags: dojo

I have a onsubmit dojo/method within a custom templated widget like so:

try {
                    if (this.validate()) {
                        //console.debug(this);
                        SubmitForm(dojo.hitch(this, this.Send));
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.debug(e);
                }
                return false;

When I call this, the scope within the dojo/method is dijit.Form. How would I go about getting the scope of the template widget instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing this:

dojo.connect(dojo.byId(this.form.id), "onsubmit",
                    dojo.hitch(this, function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if (this.GetForm().validate()) {
                            SubmitForm(dojo.hitch(this, this.Send));
                        }
                    })
                );